# coredata issue fetching data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am getting only last record from coredata? below is the my code .

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;

NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
[object setValue:@"infosys" forKey:@"cname"];
[object setValue:@"01" forKey:@"compID"];
[object setValue:@"Pune" forKey:@"locaation"];

[object setValue:@"wipro" forKey:@"cname"];
[object setValue:@"02" forKey:@"compID"];
[object setValue:@"Mumbai" forKey:@"locaation"];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (result.count<=0) {

    NSLog(@"No User Found");          
}
else{

    NSString *cname;        
    NSString *compID;   
    NSString *locaation;

    for (NSManagedObject  *obj in result) {

        cname=[obj valueForKey:@"cname"];
        compID=[obj valueForKey:@"compID"];
        locaation=[obj valueForKey:@"locaation"];


    }

    NSLog(@"Store Data = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",cname,compID,locaation]);        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add objects like this,

```
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[object setValue:@"infosys" forKey:@"cname"];
[object setValue:@"01" forKey:@"compID"];
[object setValue:@"Pune" forKey:@"locaation"];


NSManagedObject *object2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[object2 setValue:@"wipro" forKey:@"cname"];
[object2 setValue:@"02" forKey:@"compID"];
[object2 setValue:@"Mumbai" forKey:@"locaation"];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (result.count<=0) {

    NSLog(@"No User Found");

}
else{

    NSString *cname;
    NSString *compID;
    NSString *locaation;

    for (NSManagedObject  *obj in result) {

        cname=[obj valueForKey:@"cname"];
        compID=[obj valueForKey:@"compID"];
        locaation=[obj valueForKey:@"locaation"];

        NSLog(@"Store Data = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",cname,compID,locaation]);
    }



}
```

Comment: i want to store emp as one object and cname,compID and location with there property and fetch one emp obj

Comment: @PrashantBorade for that first you will need to create a table for company and another table for employee and employee table will be in relation of company table in short you will need to create relational database for that refre this for tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505

Comment: @PrashantBorade here your mistake was that you we updating existing object with different values so you were only getting the last updated values not both

Comment: every time data is saved and incresed one by one when i run the project .

Comment: yes because every time you are running project you are creating new object every time with above code that's why it will keep increasing so first I suggest you to  please go through some basics of core data in ios objective c